# So what's the point of Runnable when you can't change a class's run() function?

Tags: java, methods

I have a `Button` class, and I'm trying to implement some sort of "on click" support using Runnable and either Thread or Executor. However, every tutorial I have seen does not tell you how to change the run() method for every instance of the class. The run() function for a class seems unchangeable when implementing it. The best I can do is extend `Button` for every instance that I want a button to do something *slightly* different, so, for example, I'll have a class named `ThatOneButtonThatIsInSceneTwelveThatStartsTheRound`, and so on. Reading the Javadoc for Runnable, that is exactly what Runnable was meant to help you avoid. Am I missing something? How exactly do I make instances of the same class have different run() functions? And if that is impossible, are there other alternatives?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I'm using LibGDX, if that helps.

Comment: why would you want to change the run method for every instance?

Comment: Are you talking about `java.awt.Button` or some other `Button` class?

Comment: why do you expect the same code to behave differently for another instance? I'm not sure if you're looking for an if/else or some kind of inheritance, or something else entirely

Comment: I would expect that you would add a listener to the button to describe its behaviour.

Comment: Keep in mind that Runnable is a FunctionalInterface, so any method with no parameters and no return type can be used as a Runnable. In addition to injecting a Runnable, you can just override your onClick method on each instance, this would actually be idiomatic java and is the whole point of Anonymous Inner Classes

Comment: @Stultuske Different buttons do different things, but they inherit the same properties, such as render methods and things like width, etc.

Comment: @Eran It's a home-brew Button class that extends from my home-brew GameObject class, which was tailored over LibGDX's Rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a Runnable in the constructor of your Button class, like this:

```
public Button(Runnable onClick) {
    this.onClick = onClick;
}
```

Then you can call that Runnable when a click is detected:

```
this.onClick.run();
```

You can also pass the Runnable in a separate method, like `setOnClickListener`.

On the other hand, you shouldn't really use Runnable for these usecases, as they are designed to run on a different Thread and don't allow passing arguments, which could be rather helpful in a click listener. Use a Interface with only one method, where you can pass arguments.

```
interface MyClickListener {
    void onClick(/* your arguments here */);
}
```

Comment: All right. The solution seems simple enough, but I guess I was a little confused about initialization due to `Runnable` being an interface and not a class. I guess I still have a lot to learn... Thanks!

Comment: No problem, everybody starts as a beginner! If you have more questions, please feel free to message me.